# TFS - Source Control > Undo pending changes... VS 2019

Tags: tfs, tfvc

I right clicked a file and choose **Source Control** > **Undo pending changes...** in VS 2019 a List appeared and There was the selected file checked I Clicked Undo changes and a dialog appeared informing something that I choose 'yes'.

I wanted the red check mark from the file go, so that It is not checkin. and is undone Localy.

is this action did anything in the server that affect other programmers or it is only Local?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> is this action did anything in the server that affect other programmers or it is only Local?

First you need to check whether the workspace is **Sever** or **Local**.

[image]

If the workspace is Server, it could affect other programmers.

If the workspace is Local, the change will only happen locally.

Comment: The workspace being local versus server has **no** impact on whether others are affected. The answer to the question is strictly "no". Undoing pending changes is *always* a local operation.

Comment: when the workspace  is server type ，you do the local operation.it still can affect other users. i have shared two situation so why this is no？

Comment: Undoing pending changes in your workspace has no effect whatsoever on anyone else regardless of workspace type.